# How to dynamically manipulate variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, wxpython

```
for i in range(1,6):
        r_choice = 'r_choice' + str(i)
        self.r_choice.Show() #This is the line I want to format
```

I'd like to format the marked line in the code so that the loop would execute commands like this:

```
self.r_choice1.Show()
self.r_choice2.Show()
self.r_choice3.Show()
self.r_choice4.Show()
self.r_choice5.Show()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: If we assume that `self.r_choiceX` is a `wx.Choice` then it has a function `GetString(n)` which returns the label of the item with the given index and `GetCurrentSelection()` which speaks for itself.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to access an object's attributes, you may want to use  `getattr`. If your object is called `self`, then:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    getattr(self, 'r_choice{}'.format(i)).Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval.

Here is an example:

```
a1 = 1
a2 = 2
for i in range(1,3):
    eval(f"print(a{i})")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'\n'` for that see this code

```
print('day', 1,  '\n',  'hi')
```

Output:

```
Day 1
Hi
```

Here backslah n creates a new line then prints hi

Use this in your code